# Unable to demangle while trying to remote debug C++ with vscode

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, gdb, remote-debugging, demangler

I am trying to debug remote application with vscode insiders and ssh remote. If I set

```
"externalConsole": true
```

in `launch.json` it doesn't work at all. If I set it to false it works, but breakpoints are impossible. If I set

```
"stopAtEntry": true
```

it runs and stops at first line of the program, but if any breakpoint set `gdb` ends with error

```
/build/gdb-cXfXJ3/gdb-7.11.1/gdb/cp-support.c:1608: demangler-warning: unable to demangle '...' (demangler failed with signal 11)
A problem internal to GDB has been detected,
further debugging may prove unreliable.
Quit this debugging session? (y or n) [answered Y; input not from terminal]
ERROR: GDB exited unexpectedly. Debugging will now abort.
```

what can be done?